# Map linetype to data in plotly figure with multiple subplots in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I'm trying to map linetype to a categorical data column in a `pandas` dataframe in a `plotly` figure with multiple subplots.

I have a dataframe `df` equivalent to:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='01/01/2020',periods=100),
                   'y_one':np.linspace(1,100,100),
                   'y_two':np.linspace(100,1,100)})
df['today'] = df.date.apply(lambda date: 'the_future' if date > datetime.today() else 'the_past')
```

I need to plot multiple lines (`y_one`, `y_two`) over `date_range`. I'd like to have the lines solid for the past and dashed for the future, i.e. have linetype mapped to `df['today']`.

The plotly code I've implemented so far is:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.offline import plot
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["date"],
        y=df["y_one"],
        mode="lines",
        line=dict(color='black',
                    )
        )
    )
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["date"],
        y=df["y_two"],
        mode="lines",
        line=dict(color='red'),
        )
    )
plot(fig)
```

Is there a way to implement this use case in `plotly` with multiple subplots?

Comment: No need for `plotly.offline` with recent versions of plotly

Comment: Possibly not in a `jupyter notebook`, but I'm working in `spyder`, and `fig.show()` was not showing the figure. My solution is [recommended](https://community.plot.ly/t/plotly-for-spyder/10527). I perhaps should have said.

Comment: I see. I don't think that will affect much my answer.

Comment: Yeah, your solution works in `spyder` with `plot(fig)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly not the most elegant solution but you can eventually work with loops if you have a large number of columns to plot you can consider to use a loop.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(start='01/01/2020',periods=100),
                   'y_one':np.linspace(1,100,100),
                   'y_two':np.linspace(100,1,100)})

df["is_future"] = df["date"]>pd.datetime.today()

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df[df["is_future"]==False]["date"],
        y=df[df["is_future"]==False]["y_one"],
        mode="lines",
        legendgroup="y_one",
        name = "y_one",
        line=dict(color='black',)))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df[df["is_future"]==True]["date"],
        y=df[df["is_future"]==True]["y_one"],
        mode="lines",
        legendgroup="y_one",
        name = "y_one",
        showlegend=False,
        line=dict(color='black',dash='dash')))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df[df["is_future"]==False]["date"],
        y=df[df["is_future"]==False]["y_two"],
        mode="lines",
        legendgroup="y_two",
        name = "y_two",
        line=dict(color='red'),))

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df[df["is_future"]==True]["date"],
        y=df[df["is_future"]==True]["y_two"],
        mode="lines",
        legendgroup="y_two",
        name = "y_two",
        showlegend=False,
        line=dict(color='red', dash='dash'),))


fig.show()
```

[image]